# Problem in simplifying hypergeometric sums with integer parameters

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation

I am puzzled and slightly disturbed. Any help is appreciated, I think I will also call *Mathematica*.

```
a[j_, q_] := If[q >= j, (2 q - 1 - j)! q!/((2 q - 1)! j! (q - j)!), 0];
b[j_, q_] := ((q - j)/q) a[j, q];
Q[z_, q_] := Sum[a[j, q]*(-z)^j, {j, 0, q}];
P[z_, q_] := Sum[b[j, q]*(z)^j, {j, 0, q - 1}];
QQ[z_, q_] := Expand[D[Q[z, q], z]];
PP[z_, q_] := Expand[D[P[z, q], z]];
HH[z_, q_] := Expand[PP[z, q]*Q[z, q] - P[z, q]*QQ[z, q]];
GG[z_, q_] := Expand[Q[z, q]^2*Q[-z, q]^2];
HHH[s_, q_] := HH[z, q] /. z -> I*s;
GGG[s_, q_] := GG[z, q] /. z -> I*s;
UU[s_, q_] := FullSimplify[Expand[HHH[s, q]*HHH[-s, q]]];
WW[s_, q_] := FullSimplify[Expand[GGG[s, q]]];
CCC[s_, q_] := Expand[WW[s, q] - UU[s, q]];
FullSimplify[CCC[s, q], Assumptions -> q ∈ Integers && q >= 1]
```

There is no way in the world that answer is 0, but that's what *Mathematica* gives. Strangely enough, if I pick any integer (positive) value for `q`, then computation is correct! How can this be?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe that the issue is that the lines `WW[s_, q_] := FullSimplify[Expand[GGG[s, t]]];' and `UU[s_, q_] := FullSimplify[Expand[HHH[s, t]*HHH[-s, t]]];' do not make too much sense unless you declare how `t` depends on`q`.

Comment: @marmot, that was my bad, I was trying to figure out, and played with variables. t should be q, fixed that. But problem is still there! good eye!

Comment: Does it still simplify to `0`?

Comment: @MichaelE2, unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm, it does not for me, but, after checking, it seems numerically equivalent to zero.

Comment: Please do not use the `bugs` tag until the bug has been vetted by the community (read the `bugs` tag description).

Comment: Since you're taking derivatives, consider using `Piecewise[]` instead of `If[]`. You might also be interested in `Wronskian[]`.

Comment: @march, I did not read the tag description, but it seems like it is a bug. Numerically I am getting zero, and everything I did is legitimate. And, apparently I am not alone. Sorry if I offended someone by putting bugs tag, and I will be really happy if it turns out that it is not a bug.

Comment: No one was offended. It's standard practice here to let newcomers know about the bugs tag, because it's kind of a special tag. It might be a bug, but we like for the bug to be vetted by those expert users who might be able to explain why it's *not*.

Comment: I changed the `If` to a `Piecewise` as was suggested by @J.M. and also changed the `FullSimplify` to `Together` in defining `UU` and `WW`. With that done, the end result does not simplify to 0. As a guess, taking a derivative of `If` is, well, iffy. One is mixing a symbolic notion with procedural code, and sometimes that works fine but not always.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, I tried what you suggested, but it is "running" for the last hour. no result produced.

Comment: can this really not be reduced to a more minimal example? And please think up a better title for the question.

Comment: @george2079, I am not sure what I should change the title to? it is a summation problem at its best, and that's why I am using mathematica, and mathematica fails performing the most basic thing that a computational software should manage. I am open to suggestion.

Comment: if you think `Sum` is the issue put that in the title. But do you really need to bury it in 10 layers of delayed sets to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Pretty much any subject header specific to the functionality would be an improvement over "Possible bug in Mathematica". Maybe "Problem in simplification of hypergeometrics with integer argument assumptions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This got too long for a comment. Maybe somebody could finish this.)

Upon actually trying it out myself, I noticed something wrong:

```
a[j_, q_] = Piecewise[{{(2 q - 1 - j)! q!/((2 q - 1)! j! (q - j)!), q >= j}}, 0];
b[j_, q_] = ((q - j)/q) a[j, q];

Sum[a[j, q] (-z)^j, {j, 0, q}]
   Piecewise[{{1, q == 0}}, Hypergeometric1F1[-q, 1 - 2 q, -z]]
```

Check:

```
Limit[Hypergeometric1F1[-q, 1 - 2 q, -z], q -> 0]
   1
```

which means I can just use the Kummer function itself.

```
Q[z_, q_] = Hypergeometric1F1[-q, 1 - 2 q, -z];
```

Now, for the other one:

```
Sum[b[j, q] z^j, {j, 0, q - 1}]
   Piecewise[{{1, q == 1}}, (-z Hypergeometric1F1[1 - q, 2 - 2 q, z] -
                             Hypergeometric1F1[-q, 1 - 2 q, z] +
                             2 q Hypergeometric1F1[-q, 1 - 2 q, z])/(-1 + 2 q)]
```

Hmm, a bit more complicated, but the Kummer functions remain familiar. Let's do a test again:

```
With[{q = 1}, (-z Hypergeometric1F1[1 - q, 2 - 2 q, z] -
               Hypergeometric1F1[-q, 1 - 2 q, z] + 
               2 q Hypergeometric1F1[-q, 1 - 2 q, z])/(-1 + 2 q)]
   -1 - 2 z + 2 (1 + z)

Limit[(-z Hypergeometric1F1[1 - q, 2 - 2 q, z] - 
       Hypergeometric1F1[-q, 1 - 2 q, z] + 
       2 q Hypergeometric1F1[-q, 1 - 2 q, z])/(-1 + 2 q), q -> 1]
   1/2 (1 - E^z (-1 + z))
```

Well… that ain't right. Should've been `1`. Tells us things are a bit iffy.

So, here's a little trick I often do: *index flipping*. Do it like this:

```
Sum[b[q - 1 - j, q] z^(q - 1 - j), {j, 0, q - 1}]
   Piecewise[{{(z^(-1 + q) q!^2)/(q (-1 + q)! (-1 + 2 q)!), q == 1}},
             (z^(2 q) q! HypergeometricU[1 + q, 1 + 2 q, z])/(-1 + 2 q)!]
```

where now it is the Tricomi function (the other solution of the confluent hypergeometric DE along with the Kummer function) that is involved. Do a check again:

```
With[{q = 1},
     {(z^(-1 + q) q!^2)/(q (-1 + q)! (-1 + 2 q)!),
      (z^(2 q) q! HypergeometricU[1 + q, 1 + 2 q, z])/(-1 + 2 q)!}]
   {1, 1}
```

Ah!

So, one can now do

```
P[z_, q_] = (z^(2 q) q!)/(2 q - 1)! HypergeometricU[1 + q, 1 + 2 q, z];
```

At this juncture, it might be profitable to flip the summation index for the other function as well:

```
 Sum[a[q - j, q] (-z)^(q - j), {j, 0, q}]
```

which, after some massaging, results in

```
Q[z_, q_] = (z^(2 q) (q - 1)!)/(2 q - 1)! HypergeometricU[q, 1 + 2 q, -z];
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed effort. 
I am not fully following what you have done here, I have absolutely no clue about Tricomi function or Kummer function. But I do not have to understand everything anyway! are you suggesting that I should replace P[z,q] and Q[z,q] with  
(z^(2 q) q!)/(2 q - 1)! HypergeometricU[1 + q, 1 + 2 q, z]
and 
(z^(2 q) (q - 1)!)/(2 q - 1)! HypergeometricU[q, 1 + 2 q, -z] ?
I do not think they are equal. I looked up the definition of HypergeometricU, and if I subsitute, I am just getting 1 in both scenarios, neither P nor Q. I am sure I got this wrong.

Comment: You certainly didn't need to take my word for it. You could have verified it yourself if you were sufficiently paranoid: `{Table[Sum[a[j, q] (-z)^j, {j, 0, q}] == (z^(2 q) (q - 1)!)/(2 q - 1)! HypergeometricU[q, 1 + 2 q, -z] // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify, {q, 50}], Table[Sum[(q - j)/q a[j, q] z^j, {j, 0, q - 1}] == (z^(2 q) q!)/(2 q - 1)! HypergeometricU[1 + q, 1 + 2 q, z] // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify, {q, 50}]}`

Comment: @J,M. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a real answer, but the problem is that you should have used `=` instead of `:=` in many places.

```
a[j_, q_] := If[q >= j, (2 q - 1 - j)! q!/((2 q - 1)! j! (q - j)!), 0];
b[j_, q_] := ((q - j)/q) a[j, q];
Q[z_, q_] = Sum[a[j, q]*(-z)^j, {j, 0, q}];
P[z_, q_] = Sum[b[j, q]*(z)^j, {j, 0, q - 1}];
QQ[z_, q_] = Expand[D[Q[z, q], z]];
PP[z_, q_] = Expand[D[P[z, q], z]];
HH[z_, q_] = Expand[PP[z, q]*Q[z, q] - P[z, q]*QQ[z, q]];
GG[z_, q_] = Expand[Q[z, q]^2*Q[-z, q]^2];
HHH[s_, q_] = HH[I s, q];
GGG[s_, q_] = GG[I s, q];
UU[s_, q_] = FullSimplify[Expand[HHH[s, q]*HHH[-s, q]]];
WW[s_, q_] = FullSimplify[Expand[GGG[s, q]]];
CCC[s_, q_] = Expand[WW[s, q] - UU[s, q]];
FullSimplify[CCC[s, q], Assumptions -> q \[Element] Integers && q >= 1]
```

works and yields a nonzero result.

Comment: If at the end you add the line `% // FunctionExpand // Simplify` you will get `0`

Comment: @marmot, thanks for the suggestion, but I am still getting zero.

Comment: @BobHanlon, thanks, yes, it still do not work,.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version with the `If` replaced by Piecewise`. The timings seem reasonable and the simplifcation does not give 0.

```
a[j_, q_] := 
 Piecewise[{{(2 q - 1 - j)! q!/((2 q - 1)! j! (q - j)!), q >= j}}, 0]
b[j_, q_] := ((q - j)/q) a[j, q];
Q[z_, q_] := Sum[a[j, q]*(-z)^j, {j, 0, q}];
P[z_, q_] := Sum[b[j, q]*(z)^j, {j, 0, q - 1}];
QQ[z_, q_] := Expand[D[Q[z, q], z]];
PP[z_, q_] := Expand[D[P[z, q], z]];
HH[z_, q_] := Expand[PP[z, q]*Q[z, q] - P[z, q]*QQ[z, q]];
GG[z_, q_] := Expand[Q[z, q]^2*Q[-z, q]^2];
HHH[s_, q_] := HH[z, q] /. z -> I*s;
GGG[s_, q_] := GG[z, q] /. z -> I*s;
UU[s_, q_] := Together[Expand[HHH[s, q]*HHH[-s, q]]];
WW[s_, q_] := Together[Expand[GGG[s, q]]];
CCC[s_, q_] := Expand[WW[s, q] - UU[s, q]];

In[273]:= AbsoluteTiming[expr = CCC[s, q];]

(* Out[273]= {5.41422, Null} *)
```

Check size:

```
In[274]:= LeafCount[expr]

(* Out[274]= 1026 *)
```

Now do the simplification.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 exprfs = FullSimplify[expr, 
   Assumptions -> q \[Element] Integers && q >= 1]]

(* Out[275]= {31.587186, Hypergeometric1F1[-q, 1 - 2*q, (-I)*s]^2*
       Hypergeometric1F1[-q, 1 - 2*q, I*s]^2 - (1/(1 - 2*q)^4)*
       (Hypergeometric1F1[1 - q, 2 - 2*q, (-I)*s]*
     Hypergeometric1F1[1 - q, 2 - 2*q, 

      I*s]*((-1 + 2*q)*((-I)*q + s)*
        Hypergeometric1F1[-q, 1 - 2*q, (-I)*s] - 
             (-1 + q)*s*Hypergeometric1F1[-q, 2 - 2*q, (-I)*s])*
          ((-1 + 2*q)*(I*q + s)*
        Hypergeometric1F1[-q, 1 - 2*q, I*s] - 
             (-1 + q)*s*Hypergeometric1F1[-q, 2 - 2*q, I*s])) - 
     (1/(1 - 2*q)^2)*(Hypergeometric1F1[1 - q, 2 - 2*q, I*s]*
            Hypergeometric1F1[-q, 1 - 2*q, (-I)*s]*
            ((-1 + 2*q)*(q + I*s)*
         Hypergeometric1F1[-q, 1 - 2*q, (-I)*s] - 
               I*(-1 + q)*s*Hypergeometric1F1[-q, 2 - 2*q, (-I)*s])*

      Piecewise[{{(2*(-1 + q)*Hypergeometric1F1[1 - q, 2 - 2*q, I*s] - 

            I*s*Hypergeometric1F1[2 - q, 3 - 2*q, I*s])/(-2 + 4*q), 
         q > 1}}, 0] + 
          Hypergeometric1F1[-q, 1 - 2*q, I*s]*Piecewise[
              {{(2*(-1 + q)*
             Hypergeometric1F1[1 - q, 2 - 2*q, (-I)*s] + 

            I*s*Hypergeometric1F1[2 - q, 3 - 2*q, (-I)*s])/(-2 + 
            4*q), q > 1}}, 0]*
            (Hypergeometric1F1[1 - q, 2 - 2*q, (-I)*s]*
                 ((-1 + 2*q)*(q - I*s)*
            Hypergeometric1F1[-q, 1 - 2*q, I*s] + 

           I*(-1 + q)*s*Hypergeometric1F1[-q, 2 - 2*q, I*s]) + 
               (1 - 2*q)^2*Hypergeometric1F1[-q, 1 - 2*q, (-I)*s]*

         Piecewise[{{(2*(-1 + q)*
                Hypergeometric1F1[1 - q, 2 - 2*q, I*s] - 

               I*s*Hypergeometric1F1[2 - q, 3 - 2*q, I*s])/(-2 + 
               4*q), q > 1}}, 0]))} *)
```

Check size again:

In[276]:= LeafCount[exprfs]

(* Out[276]= 541 *)

Comment: thank you very much. Do you think is it possible to simplify HyperGeometric bits in the output, basically what I am asking is that about the possibility of having hypergeo-free output?

Comment: Could do with `Assuming[q > 1, FunctionExpand[Simplify[expression]]]` but result will be longer. Then do the `q==1` case separately.

Comment: @Nez, doesn't seem likely to get something without hypergeometrics, unless you fix a particular value of `q`.